# Need Share Taxonomies Across a Network all sites

Tags: wordpress, global, multisite, taxonomy-terms

I used Wordpress Multisite Network concept in site.
But I need Product category share across a Network all sites.
Means I will add category in main site only and I can use main site category in all sub-sites. 
so is this possible?
I already used this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/mu-global-terms/
this plugin works fine but when I add new site then all categories automatic remove in DB.
Please suggest this type of any plugin or solution for it.
In advance thank you all.